# Hide slide numbers and slide footer on first and second slide in LibreOffice Impress

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I use LibreOffice Impress for to create my presentations. I am wondering how I can choose **not** to show the slide footer (including e.g. the slide numbers, presentation title and date) not only on the first, but also on the second slide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are able to create more than one master slide (or slide template), and you can select which one to use when picking the slide design for each slide.  To do this:

1. Go to View -> Master -> Slide Master, and then click "New Master".
2. Set up the new master template to be way you want for the first and second (and any other) slides, ie. no slide footer, no page numbering, etc.
3. Close the Master View.
4. Right-click on your first slide in the slide pane and choose "Slide Design".
5. Choose the new master you created in step 2, and click "ok".
6. Do the same for your second slide and so forth.

You can use these to create any number of different slide designs, some with numbering, some with special column formatting or whatever.  Hope that helps.